# Should I use get_/set_ prefixes in Python method names?

Tags: python, coding-style

In Python, properties are used instead of the Java-style getters and setters. So one rarely sees `get...` or `set...` methods in the public interfaces of classes.

But, in cases where a property is not appropriate, one might still end up with methods that behave like getters or setters. Now for my questions: Should these method names start with `get_` / `set_`? Or, is this unpythonic verbosity since it is often obvious of what is meant (and one can still use the docstring to clarify non-obvious situations)?

This might be a matter of personal taste, but I would be interested in what the majority thinks about this. What would you prefer as an API user?

For example, say we have an object representing multiple cities. One might have a method `get_city_by_postalcode(postalcode)` or one could use the shorter method `city_by_postalcode`. I tend towards the latter.

Comment: "cases were a property is not appropriate " having trouble with this.  An example would help.  Properties are so useful it's hard to imagine any place where they'd be inappropriate.

Comment: @S.Lott: What about the example I provided? It isn't a getter in the usual sense, but `get` might be the most fitting verb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think shorter is better, so I tend to prefer the latter. But what's important is to be consistent within your project: don't mix the two methods. If you jump into someone else's project, keep what the other developers chose initially.

Answer (score 7):

You won't ever lose the chance to make your property behave like a getter/setter later by using [descriptors](https://web.archive.org/web/20081216014119/http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm). If you want to change a property to be read-only, you can also replace it with a getter method with the same name as the property and decorate it with `@property`. So, my advice is to avoid getters/setters unless the project you are working on already uses them because you can always change your mind later and make properties read-only, write-only, or whatever without modifying the interface to your class.

Answer (score 4):

If it's usable as a property (one value to get or set, and no other parameters, I usually do:

```
class Foo(object):

    def _get_x(self):
        pass

    def _set_x(self, value):
        pass

    x = property(_get_x, _set_x)
```

If the getter/setter is any more complex than that, I would use get_x and set_x:

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it done both ways. Coming from an Objective-C background, I usually do `foo()/set_foo()` if I can't use a property (although I try to use properties whenever possible). It doesn't really matter that much, though, *as long as you're consistent*.

(Of course, in your example, I wouldn't call the method `get_city_by_postalcode()` at all; I'd probably go with `translate_postalcode` or something similar that uses a better action verb in the name.)

Comment: Actually, I think "get_city_by_postalcode" is more descriptive than "translate_postalcode".

Answer (score 0):

If I have to use a getter/setter, I like it this way:

Suppose you have a variable self._x. Then x() would return the value of self._x, and setX(x) would set the value of self._x